# ERROR: Public Key Cannot be Exposed

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, tezos-signer, taquito

```
tezbridge.request({method: 'post_source'})

taquito.Tezos.setProvider({rpc: 'https://rpc.tzkt.io/mainnet', signer: new taquitoTezbridgeSigner.TezBridgeSigner()})

taquito.Tezos.contract.transfer({ to: 'tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb ', amount: 0.001 }).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

[image]

whenever I try to send any tezos I am getting this error I have tried every possible method available on the internet I know I am making but I just cannot find where it is, I have tried different keys but it is not working. hoping to get a better solution from seniors 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you revealed the public key for `tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb`? You must reveal the key before you can transfer. You only have to do this once before you send for the first time.

Comment: can you guide me how can i do that?

Comment: Check the documentation for taquito. There should be a function you can use to reveal. Taquito is a 3rd party library for Tezos; they should have docs/support/examples.